# Display array_key from PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

**Here I am Having an Issue:**

I have two arrays like the following:

```
  $array1 = array('1','2','1','3','1');
  $array2 = array('1','2','3'); // Unique $array1 values
```

with array2 values i need all keys of an array1

**Expected Output Is:**

```
 1 => 0,2,4
 2 => 1
 3 => 3
```

here it indicates `array2 value` =>`array1 keys`

Comment: i have tried with array_search(1, $array1) it is displaying only one matching key.............

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $index => $value) {
  $result[$value][] = $index;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I needed this

Answer (score 1):

If you pass [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) a 2nd parameter, it'll give you all the keys with that value.

So, just loop through `$array2` and get the keys from `$array1`.

```
$result = array();
foreach($array2 as $val){
    $result[$val] = array_keys($array1, $val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do the job. It will create a result array in which the attribute val will contain the value that is searched in array and keys attribute will be an array that contains the found keys. Based on your values following is an example:

```
$array1 =array('1','2','1','3','1');
$array2 =array('1','2','3');

$results = array();

foreach ($array2 as $key2=>$val2) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array1 as $key1=>$val1 ) {
        if ($val2 == $val1) {
            array_push($result,$key1);  
        }
    }
    array_push($results,array("val"=>$val2,keys=>$result ));
}

 echo json_encode($results);
```

The result will be:

```
[{"val":"1","keys":[0,2,4]},
 {"val":"2","keys":[1]},
 {"val":"3","keys":[3]}]
```